# How to get the first and second objects

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I would like to know how can I get the first and second objects of a class. I achieved it for the first object :

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"YourClassName"];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    // code
}];
```

From here, what do you suggest to get the next object ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use findObjects to get an array of matching objects.  Set a max count to return with .limit:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"YourClassName"];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
query.limit = 2;
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        // this will run up to 2 times
        NSLog("%@", object);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to add `query.limit=2;`. Here's the whole code :

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"YourClassName"];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
query.limit = 2;
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    // code
}];
```

Comment: Right about using limit, not right about calling getFirst.  Use find... to get multiple objects.